# IOS 8 asset catalog image sizes confusing

Tags: ios, iphone, image, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

Say I want to make a button that takes up half the width of the iPhone screen (portrait) at @1x. This would be 160 pixels, @2x this would be 320 pixels.

Now with iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus it gets confusing. The iPhone 6 has 750 pixels width and uses @2x but the asset catalog has only one box for adding @2x images, so do I make my image 320 pixels or 375 pixels?

Also, the iPhone 6 Plus has width of 1080 pixels or 1242 pixels (any idea which one?), but my standard image of 160 pixels multiplied by 3 = 480 pixels but half the iPhone 6 Plus screen is either 540 pixels or 621 pixels??

What size I should be making my images and why?

Comment: According to Apple's website, the iPhone 6 Plus is 1080 pixels wide.

Comment: Nice question but the answer does not make sense!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone 6 and 6 Plus have the same aspect ration as the iPhone 5/5C/5S, so they automatically scale the image for your screen.  For the iPhone 6, your image should be 320 pixels, just like with a 4-inch screen.

For the 6 Plus, you should make it 480 pixels for the same reason.

Comment: Would that not make the 480 pixel image stretch to 540 pixels?

Comment: @Pulsarman325 The aspect ration on the 6 and 6 Plus is the same as on the 5, so that would not stretch it.

Comment: I still don't quite understand how it does not stretch just because of the aspect ratio, but thank you for your help and ultimately you answered my question as to what size I should make my image so I will mark your answer as correct. Thanks again @NobodyNada

Comment: @Pulsarman325 You're welcome.  The aspect ratio is the ratio of width to height.  The iPhone 6 and 6 Plus are wider than the other devices, but they are also taller so the aspect ratio is the same, so instead of stretching it, the device can scale the image for the bigger screen.

Comment: I guess that I should of said the image will be upscaled rather than stretched, either way the image will not look too good, upscaling an image means loosing quality. Thanks mate