# Why are we using @2x for iPhone 5 and 6 if their screens are different?

Tags: iphone, image, size, iphone-6-plus

I'm working on an iPhone app supporting iPhone 5, 6 and 6 plus. The design includes some images that almost fit the width of the screen, according to references I have read the images are supposed to be 100% for 1x, 200% for 2x and 300% for 3x.

We are resizing the images based on the 1x for iPhone 6 and 6 plus, but they look a bit smaller than I expected. The sizes are fine, the devices are showing the corresponding ones.

My question is why are iPhone 5 and 6 using the same @2x images if their screens are different sizes? and images will look smaller on iPhone 6 and based on this 6 plus ones will look even smaller...

Comment: Welcome to [so].  You should edit your question to focus it somewhat better.  The title you've written doesn't seem to match the actual question you've asked in the last paragraph.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS 8 asset catalog image sizes confusing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187585/ios-8-asset-catalog-image-sizes-confusing)